# Difference in dates between servers

Tags: php, date, datetime, floor

I am wondering why I have been getting totally invalid computation by PHP all the time.

I have code like this:

```
echo floor((strtotime("2017-03-27") - strtotime("2017-03-24"))/86400);
```

which on the one of the server returns: `3` (like 3 days)

and on the another server returns: `2`! (2.9583333333333 day?) Why is there a variance?

Comment: Why in the world of whatever is holy are you using `floor()` for date calculations?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie is it forbidden? Good to knows, maybe it is causing my problem?

Comment: Fatal assumption that every day has 86400 assumptions

Comment: @MarkBaker a couple days from now we'll have a day with 86401 assumptions! My current wager is that in those 3 days OP's timezone has 3600 fewer assumptions than usual due to a DST change.

Comment: On the one server I have 12 precision in my php.ini, on the another server precision is 14, it's our difference isn't it?

Comment: @corey nope, that was a faulty assumption on my part. It's pretty farfetched to assume that float rounding could account for that big of a difference, I just didn't really read the numbers all that closely. It's probably a DST issue with differing timezones. I suggest doing UTC everywhere all the time forever.

Comment: Yep, pretty much all of the eastern hemisphere has their DST change on March 26, 2017.

Comment: @Sammitch yes, you're absolutely right! OMG, though we use DST in Poland... Thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, just use better methods:

**EDIT** I updated the code to use the same dates as OP. It returns **3**, as it should, and I'm fairly confident it will do that on whatever server you put it on to test.

```
<?php

$date1 = date_create('2017-03-27');
$date2 = date_create('2017-03-24');

$interval = date_diff($date1,$date2);

echo $interval->format('%a');

?>
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Answer (score 0):

Your servers maybe sitting in two different time zones. Convert the days to hours and you will get a difference of one hour.

```
3 days        * 24 hours/1 day = 72 hours
2.958333 days * 24 hours/1 day = 71 hours
```

Comment: I suppose it could also be a DST change since the dates are in March.

Comment: @Sammitch DST is on Sunday, March 12 for most states in the US **assuming** Corey is in the US, so if both servers are in the same Time Zone than DST would not matter. More than likely one server is in a Time Zero greater than the other by 1 hour.

Comment: DST change is March 26 for pretty much the rest of the world.

Comment: Check the answer I just posted for a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Since some people are having difficulty accepting that this is due to a TZ-specific DST change, have some proof:

```
function poc($tz_str) {
        $tz = new DateTimeZone($tz_str);
        $start = (new DateTime('2017-03-24', $tz))->format('U');
        $end = (new DateTime('2017-03-27', $tz))->format('U');

        return [$tz_str, $end - $start, ( $end - $start ) / 86400];
}

var_dump(
        poc('UTC'),
        poc('Europe/London'),
        poc('America/New_York')
);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(3) "UTC"
  [1]=> int(259200)
  [2]=> int(3)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(13) "Europe/London"
  [1]=> int(255600)
  [2]=> float(2.9583333333333)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=> string(16) "America/New_York"
  [1]=> int(259200)
  [2]=> int(3)
}
```

- UTC has no DST, not affected.
- Most of the eastern hemisphere has their DST change on March 26, **affected**.
- Most of the western hemisphere has their DST change on March 12, not affected.

That said, don't do manual date math on a Unix timestamp.